# Line segment intersection

Tags: geometry, intersection, lines

I found this code snippet on raywenderlich.com, however the link to the explanation wasn't valid anymore. I "translated" the answer into Swift, I hope you can understand, it's actually quite easy even without knowing the language. Could anyone explain what exactly is going on here? Thanks for any help.

```
class func linesCross(#line1: Line, line2: Line) -> Bool {
    let denominator = (line1.end.y - line1.start.y) * (line2.end.x - line2.start.x) -
        (line1.end.x - line1.start.x) * (line2.end.y - line2.start.y)

    if denominator == 0 { return false } //lines are parallel

    let ua = ((line1.end.x - line1.start.x) * (line2.start.y - line1.start.y) -
        (line1.end.y - line1.start.y) * (line2.start.x - line1.start.x)) / denominator
    let ub = ((line2.end.x - line2.start.x) * (line2.start.y - line1.start.y) -
        (line2.end.y - line2.start.y) * (line2.start.x - line1.start.x)) / denominator

    //lines may touch each other - no test for equality here
    return ua > 0 && ua < 1 && ub > 0 && ub < 1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the code is doing.

Every point `P` in the segment `AB` can be described as:

```
P = A + u(B - A)
```

for some constant `0 <= u <= 1`. In fact, when `u=0` you get `P=A`, and you get`P=B` when `u=1.` Intermediate values of `u` will give you intermediate values of `P` in the segment. For instance, when `u = 0.5` you will get the point in the middle. In general, you can think of the parameter `u` as the ratio between the lengths of `AP` and `AB`.

[image]

Now, if you have another segment `CD` you can describe the points `Q` on it in the same way, but with a different `u`, which I will call `v`:

```
Q = C + v(D - C)
```

Again, keep in mind that `Q` lies between `C` and `D` if, and only if, `0 <= v <= 1` (same as above for `P`).

To find the intersection between the two segments you have to equate `P=Q`. In other words, you need to find `u` and `v`, both between `0` and `1` such that:

```
A + u(B - A) = C + v(D - C)
```

So, you have this equation and you have to see if it is solvable within the given constraints on `u` and `v`.

Given that `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` are points with two coordinates `x,y` each, you can open the equation above into two equations:

```
ax + u(bx - ax) = cx + v(dx - cx)
ay + u(by - ay) = cy + v(dy - cy)
```

where `ax = A.x`, `ay = A.y`, etc., are the coordinates of the points.

Now we are left with a 2x2 linear system. In matrix form:

```
|bx-ax  cx-dx| |u| = |cx-ax|
|by-ay  cy-dy| |v|   |cy-ay|
```

The determinant of the matrix is

```
det = (bx-ax)(cy-dy) - (by-ay)(cx-dx)
```

This quantity corresponds to the `denominator` of the code snippet (please check).

Now, multiplying both sides by the cofactor matrix:

```
|cy-dy  dx-cx|
|ay-by  bx-ax|
```

we get

```
det*u = (cy-dy)(cx-ax) + (dx-cx)(cy-ay)
det*v = (ay-by)(cx-ax) + (bx-ax)(cy-ay)
```

which correspond to the variables `ua` and `ub` defined in the code (check this too!)

Finally, once you have `u` and `v` you can check whether they are both between `0` and `1` and in that case return that there is intersection. Otherwise, there isn't.

Answer (score 2):

You can find a detailed segment-intersection algorithm 
in the book [*Computational Geometry in C*](http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/books/compgeom.html), Sec. 7.7.
The `SegSegInt` code described there is available [*here*](http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/books/ftp.html).
I recommend avoiding slope calculations.

There are several "degenerate" cases that require care: collinear segments
overlapping or not, one segment endpoint in the interior of the other segments,
etc. I wrote the code to return an indication of these special cases.

Answer (score 0):

For a given line the slope is

```
m=(y_end-y_start)/(x_end-x_start)
```

if two slopes are equal, the lines are parallel

```
m1=m1

(y1_end-y_start)/(x1_end-x1_start)=(y2_end-y2_start)/(x2_end-x2_start)
```

And this is equivalent to checking that the denominator is not zero,

Regarding the rest of the code, find the explanation on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection) under "Given two points on each line"

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the denominator, however I've already seen the article on wikipedia and I didn't really understand it because I don't have the basic math knowledge actually - I'm only in tenth grade of school...